# "Uncanny valley" but for inanimate objects

Tags: single-word-requests

Uncanny valley is the unpleasant experience one feels when confronted with something resembling a human, that isn't one (e.g., creepy Chucky Doll).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley)

> The concept suggests that humanoid objects that imperfectly resemble actual human beings provoke uncanny or strangely familiar feelings of uneasiness and revulsion in observers

What is the equivalent term when referring to objects or concepts rather than humans? That is, what term would you use to describe the sense of uneasiness when you are faced with something that looks like, say, a phone, but isn't a phone (say a phone shaped cake). Or even more abstractly, say, something "that looks like love", but isn't love.

To clarify, I'm looking for a term that emphasizes the uneasiness of the experience.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't almost all those who are afraid of phone-shaped (and remember that phones in many different shapes have existed) cakes etc also going to be afraid of actual phones? Humans / humanoids may have an explanation depending on fear of a master-race, but a cake is rarely a threat, no matter what shape it is made into.

Comment: Why do you think that 'uncanny valley' could not make sense as a description of your examples, the abstract as well as the concrete.  The description, after all, refers to the feelings of the human observing not of the thing, being or idea perceived

Comment: Does 'cognitive dissonance' or even 'cognitive shock'?work? i.e. "The term cognitive dissonance is used to describe the mental discomfort that results from holding two conflicting beliefs, values, or attitudes. People tend to seek consistency in their attitudes and perceptions, so this conflict causes feelings of unease or discomfort." If this sounds like it will cover it then I will write it up...

Comment: uncanny valley sounds stupid to me. Freud said it: The uncanny or uncanniness. The concept is **umheimlich** in German. Objects don't have feelings, humans do.

Comment: I'm not sure that the concept itself extends into this region. I have always thought it was particular to almost humans.

Comment: @Tuffy uncanny valley refers to "humanoid objects"

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine That's definitely a related experience, but I think cognitive dissonance has a very strict psychological definition and also it doesn't describe the experience, but rather the operation.

Comment: @Lambie Uncanny Valley does not refer to objects having feelings but rather to the human observer. Perhaps I misunderstand your comment. However, Umheimlich is a very contender for what I'm after! Thanks

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm trying to write about the uneasiness of seeing something that you know isn't what it appears to be.

Comment: A phone-shaped cake does not seem to be a very good example of what the question is about: it is far too obviously unlike an actual phone to be in the uncanny valley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the examples in your post don't necessarily point to the "valley" part of the uncanny valley phenomenon, I would suggest that the word you're looking for is simply "uncanny."

Wikipedia, citing Nicholas Royle's book *The Uncanny: An Introduction*, defines it as "the psychological experience of something as not simply mysterious, but creepy, often in a strangely familiar way."

Freud's work on the uncanny describes it in a similar way, noting that it is a feeling produced through a meeting of the *heimlich* (homelike; familiar) and *unheimlich* (unhomelike; unfamiliar).

To return to your question, I would argue that, while the uncanny *valley* is specific to humanoids (as practically all of the theories behind it have something to do with survival instincts, pathogen aversion, or our social nature), the definitions noted above would support using "uncanny" to describe something that looks like a phone but isn't, or "looks like love," but isn't.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. +1 I think uncanny valley is nonsense, myself.

Comment: I follow your reasoning but when I look in the dictionary "uncanny" really doesn't fit. From Merriam Webster:
a) seeming to have a supernatural character or origin : EERIE, MYSTERIOUS
b) being beyond what is normal or expected : suggesting superhuman or supernatural powers

I'm not looking to emphasizing the mysteriousness or the supernatural, rather just the uneasiness. I do like unheimlich, which I feel like describes my situation very closely.

Comment: It will depend on what you're using it for and your intended audience for sure, but this is a pretty common usage of "uncanny," despite it not being the literal dictionary definition. The usage I described is exactly how it's being used in "uncanny valley," for instance. I'd venture to say that anyone who would understand *unheimlich* would just as easily understand "uncanny" since it's the direct English translation of the Freudian term (his pivotal essay on the subject is entitled "The Uncanny" in English).

Comment: [Lexico's](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/uncanny) definition of uncanny is more general: "Strange or mysterious, especially in an unsettling way." That would fit, but isn't at all specific to this case.

Comment: If OP wants to avoid any confusion, they could add the article (i.e., write it as "the uncanny") to make it clear that they are referring to the phenomenon.

Comment: @Lambie, would you care to explain why you keep insisting so emphatically that *uncanny valley* 'is nonsense' or 'sounds stupid'? Are you saying that the **phenomenon** that the phrase stands for does not exist, or that the **term** is not apt for it, or is it merely that it is a part of a **jargon** that you find generally annoying?

Comment: @jsw29 I am saying it is industry dependent. The OP starts asking the question one way and then ends up with another. "I'm looking for a term that emphasizes the uneasiness of the experience". So, it sounds stupid to people like me who are not in the industry.

Answer (score 2):

'Uncanny Valley' is the phrase used for all these situations, for computer generated objects or artifacts that are really pretty good but not exactly right and so they give a sense of discomfort.

The canonical example is in computer graphics, where the characters in Toy Story look perfectly fine because the animation can reproduce toy's very well (the light and color of plastic is easily reproduced) but the human characters in the Polar Express, where the computer animators worked so hard to reproduce the color and luminescence of human skin and the muscle tone underlying facial expression, had this creepy uncanny feel to them.

But you can get this feeling from AI produced text, where the meaning can be off just slightly so that things feel a little weird, or the dreamscape images from GANs are more nightmarish than anything.

So the phrase 'uncanny valley' can be used to refer to the unease in close but not perfect representation of whatever object.

There's no reason to assume that the phrase is limited to human representations. It's just that they are a very good example of the phenomenon.

Comment: Yes, this computer lingo is not used by regular folks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that "There's no reason to assume that the phrase is limited to human representations"  since it's how it's defined. Also when AI produced text gives a sensation of uncanny valley it is because it attempts to appear "as if it was written by a human" referring to the original meaning requiring a "close but not quite humanoid" .

Comment: "How it's defined"? Wikipedia is just words written by a bunch of people. It's not a platonic ideal of truth. Someone there is being too specific and no one felt like editing. Or another way of saying this is, let the term 'uncanny valley' be strictly defined as relating to human facial appearances. It's still very easily used metaphorically for non-human things.

Comment: The usage [uncanny valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley) for humanoids is because there's a specific phenomenon where something nearly human looks very off, while something that's further away is less disturbing. There's a graph on the Wikipedia page that explains why it's a valley. This doesn't really apply in the same way to other non-humanoid things, so "valley" may not be appropriate. Unless you want to argue the same relationship holds.

Comment: @StuartF Just because the phrase started out that way doesn't mean it hasn't evolved. It has also been applied to the anthropomorphized animals in the musical "Cats". Technically, it only applies to humanoid robots, not CGI, if you want to pick nits about how it started.

Comment: The uncanny-valley phenomenon presupposes that people generally have a certain emotional engagement with the representation of other humans; the uncanny valley is a departure from the general pattern of such engagement. One may reasonably expect the same phenomenon to occur with respect to the representation of other objects with which people engage emotionally, but not with respect to the objects that trigger no such engagement. Whenever the phenomenon does occur, the term *uncanny valley* is, as this answer argues, quite apt; when it doesn't, the question what to call it does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this...

[***cognitive shock***](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-83089-0)

...which is based on the concept of

***cognitive dissonance***

> In the field of psychology, ***cognitive dissonance*** is the perception of contradictory information. Relevant items of information include a person's actions, feelings, ideas, beliefs, values, ***and things in the environment.***

[-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance)

> "The term cognitive dissonance is used to describe the ***mental discomfort*** that results from ***holding two conflicting beliefs***, values, or attitudes. People tend to seek consistency in their attitudes and perceptions, ***so this conflict causes feelings of unease or discomfort.***

[-WellMind.com](https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-cognitive-dissonance-2795012)

---

*I am trying to remember which writer it was that said the definition of an artist is "a bloke who can hold two conflicting ideas in mind, believe both are true, and not go insane"...probably  it was Burgess, maybe  Moore-Cornwell, ...

Comment: †Was it F. Scott Fitzgerald, in [*The Crack-Up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crack-Up)? “The test of a first-rate intelligence is the ability to hold two opposed ideas in the mind at the same time, and still retain the ability to function.”

Comment: @WeatherVane  Interesting. That may have been the origin of the expression, and maybe Burgess was paraphrasing it...as far as I can recall, the convo took place in a French bar

Comment: Yes, it's not the same but I wonder if there was a *more* original version which FSF and others worked from.

Comment: I googled your quote and that's what came up :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Now that I am thinking about it, I am starting to think I saw it in Burgess _"Earthly Powers"_. Somewhere I have a dusty dog-eared copy in my library. If I can find the exact quote I will definitely let you know. I just love locking down quotes and ambiguities...

Comment: There's something similar by George Orwell: *[Doublethink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublethink) means the power of holding two contradictory beliefs in one's mind simultaneously, and accepting both of them.*

Comment: @Justin TXS... _poco a poco_ we are finding more than a couple of versions of the idea

Answer (score 0):

***eerie***

> strange in a frightening and mysterious way:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eerie)

Please bear with me...

I am going to recount an experience I had that would explore the concept.

Back when I was a gonzo journalist living with some rock'n'rollers in a commune in upstate New York during the late  70s, my wife and I came back after a long day expecting to find the house quiet and unoccupied; after all, the band was all up in New Paltz performing. And  when we got home to the manse, and started walking up the stairs to the entrance, all was dark as expected.

However,  once  on the upper landing, through the front windows we began to see an ***eerie*** blob of dim light floating from room to room...

Supposedly the house was unoccupied, and my first thought was burglars. My second thought was superstitious. After all, the house had a bit a of a history...

The hairs on my neck rose, and I thought it best to go back...but my wife was a little more adventurous than me, and insisted we go in...

What I felt is almost impossible to describe. How do you reconcile reality with the supernatural?

That is ***eerie.***

Comment: If an alternative to 'uncanny' is what is really sought but specifically for non-human things, then 'creepy' is an alternative that is commonly used in the context of 'uncanny valley'.

Comment: @Mitch  No argument here...you should highlight that word in your answer to improve readability.

Comment: If my answer were answering in the direction of offering alternatives, I would add it. But I maintain that there is no need. In my experience in AI I find that the accepted phrase is 'the uncanny valley' whether it for humans of not. It is a very common concept easily used for many phenomena. So I'm just offering this word to you as a synonym for 'eerie' which you could use in your answer if you feel like it.

Comment: _vamos a ver_....personally, I have never heard the phrase. That said, I live in Latin America, and my only source of American vernacular is Netfilx, CNN, or here...apparently the OP is looking for a general term. If I am off-base, I apologize.

Comment: Cascabel As @Lambie noted, it's a technical term, but a fun one that came out of academia so in certain tech circles (graphics, AI) it is well known, but I have no idea outside of that. You're not off-base and even if you were, there's nothing to apologize for here, we're all answering for the language community we imagine we're talking to. No cap.